# Overwriting local JSON file in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a json file which I wish to modify. I already have a way of mapping it into a model but the thing is, I can't save it or overwrite the existing json file. I already tried `file-saver` but I learned that I won't be able to change is save directory since it depends on the setting of the browser.

I simply need to modify the json file on my `assets` folder so I can write a `get` method, which will return the modified json file.

I don't know what info I could provide but here's what I have so far:

**The JSON file:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "sampleName",
    "lastName": "sampleLastName",
    "car": {
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": "Vios",
        "year": 2017
    }
}
```

**The save method:**

```
saveJson(arg) {
  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(arg)], {type : 'application/json'});
  saveAs(blob,'test.json');
}
```

The `arg` parameter will receive the model which has the new set of data. This method always saves the new json file in the `Downloads` folder since that is where the browser points its downloaded files. I believe I have to change this one totally

Comment: Is the file you want to overwrite located on the server or locally? If locally, JavaScript in browsers is prevented by the sandbox to write to arbitrary locations.

Comment: Angule code runs in the **browser**. You want to modify a file sitting on the **server**. Code running in the browser on a different machine (but even if the browser is on the same machine) can't possibly do that. You need to send a request to your server, and the server must do the job.

Comment: @fredrik its a local json file that I placed in `assets` folder of the project. I was hoping I could edit it and if possible, return the modified values from the edited json file

Comment: That won't be possible while running in a normal browser, you will have to run it inside Electron (as VS Code does) or something similar.

Comment: I see. So whatever I do it will always be dependent on the browsers download directory. Then how about a workaround. Since this is a temp service, is it possible for angular to get the complete directory of the.. lets say the Downloads folder? I'm really new in angular. I really appreciate the help

Comment: It shouldn't be. The same sandboxing comes into effect. You can make a "upload" function in which the user selects the file - but you will most likely not be able to automatically select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I won't be able to change the directory of file saver, I looked for alternate solutions that will somehow provide the same solution. I simply used the local storage of the browser which I just discovered today. XD

Anyway, just in case a fellow beginner stumbles on the same problem and doesn't know how to use the local browser storage, here's the service I made:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MockService {
  saveJson(id, obj) {
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(obj));
  }

  getJson(id) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
  }

  removeJson(id) {
    localStorage.removeItem(id);
  }
}
```